# missing 1 required positional argument: 'response' scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, spyder

new to scrapy just trying to figure it out to see if I can use it to scrape a web serial I'm reading so I can read it offline on the way to school and I can't figure out how to fix this error I keep getting.

> TypeError: parse_wordpress() missing 1 required positional argument: 'response'

I think this means the website isn't corresponding properly but I can't think of a way to fix the issue.

```
    import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class BlogrollSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'BLOG ARCHIVER'
    allowed_domains = ['blogroll.com', 'wordpress.com', 'blogspot.com']
    start_urls = ['https://parahumans.wordpress.com/2011/06/11/1-1/']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(),
        restrict_xpaths=('//p[@title="Next Chapter"]',)),
        callback="parse_wordpress",
        follow= True),
        )

    def parse_wordpress(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        paragraphs = hxs.select("//p")
        for paragraphs in paragraphs:
            paragraph = paragraphs.select("a/text()").extract()
            print (paragraph)

        return item
blog1 = BlogrollSpider()
blog1.parse_wordpress()
print ("code is reaching here")
```

this is the website/web serial I'm trying to download : 'https://parahumans.wordpress.com/2011/06/11/1-1/'

Comment: blog1.parse_wordpress() you don't have to call this directly. Try to delete the line and call the script with `scrapy runspider <file.py>`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't call your parse function directly. It is called automatically when Scrapy gets a response.

Instead, use the [command line runner](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html).
For example, if you have a full project:

```
scrapy crawl "BLOG ARCHIVER"
```

Or if you have only a spider file:

```
scrapy runspider my_spider.py
```

Alternatively, write a [custom runner script](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html).

As an aside, I would suggest you work through the [official tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) as it covers how to run a spider.